# Unexpected token '<' in application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

When I run this Node.js application I am getting this error, and can't find the error. I have all the required packages installed.

Please review the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Please give a [mre] **as text**.

Comment: This `app.js` file seems to contain JSX

Comment: The app.js seems to be using react hooks and jsx. it not necessarily js code to be interpreted by node.js

Comment: You can't directly run JSX code. You need to transpile that JSX to actual JS code, usually with Babel or Typescript

Answer (score 0):

99% of the time, when you get “Unexpected token '<'”, what is happening is that something somewhere is trying to load a script from a URL, expecting Javascript typically, but instead getting

```
<html><body>Not found</body></html>
```

or something like that.  When it tries to interpret that text as Javascript, it yields the error you see.